# How should I binding xaml event from WPF in .net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, binding

How should I binding a event in netcore 3.0?
In a WPF project(netcore3.0), there is no kind of Interactive.dll to do like

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DoSomethingCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

so how to binding a event in WPF (netcore3.0)?

Comment: Use an implementation that supports .NET Core like for example the preview version of [Prism 7.2.0.1233](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/7.2.0.1233-pre).

Comment: after taking a quick look at Prism's overview & doc, it seems like not existing a way to handle it.

Comment: What do you mean? You should be able to simply install the preview version of the NuGet package in your .NET Core app.

Comment: Already install the prism preview, just don't know how to coding it ..binding event..

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked, and what didn't?

Comment: If you don't find a ported implementation, you may create your own one or simply handle the event in the view and invoke the command of the view model from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use a mousebinding for this.

```
  <YourControl.InputBindings>
      <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="... />
  </YourControl.InputBindings>
```

The way you're intended to use that dll now is via a nuget package - xaml bahaviors.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

Seeing as how net core 3 is still only in preview, i thought it might be rather early for this package to be updated.

Seems not though:

https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/issues/13